# Step by Step "Getting Started"Google Maps SDK for iOS issue

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

thank you beforehand.

Here is my problem:

I have the latest version of Xcode (4.5.2 I believe). I followed the getting started google maps api sdk for iphone tutorial, never did more nor less. I used the sample code google tutorial offers, changed the viewcontroller name as they explain, created the project disabling the "Use storyboards" as they suggest, in other words, I did exactly what the tutorial says but my app never shows a map, just a black view, I think it doesnt even shows a view, and the console shows the followin (warning?, error?):

2013-01-16 16:43:45.987 MapTest[9147:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

I have no idea why this could be happening. The funny thing is that I erase the google maps api ios sdk tutorial sample code and the app works, well it shows the blank view that would normally show when you create a new app. Your help would be appreciated (sorry about my english, it might suck).

Comment: sorry If I answered just soo late, personal issues. Guessing that this post still could be of some use to others I´ll share the link you asked for. Hope you can find a solution, thank your. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, from iOS 5 and above, the window of an app is required to have a root view controller to handle screen rotations correctly. From your App Delegate, you should replace the

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to

```
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

Comment: I'll try that solution and comment if it works. Thank your very much Jason Huh.

Comment: Hi.
Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me. I noticed that the applicaciont: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of my recentrly created app have the following code:
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
}

Comment: @user1908023, thanks for the update. Could you share the full code inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or let me know the link of the iphone tutorial you mentioned in the original post?

Comment: Sorry I answered so late, personal issues. Guessing that this post still could be of some use to others, here is the link you asked for, hope you can finde a solution. Thank you. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable "Google Maps SDK for iOS". in your google account console "services" tab.
Try this :)